# grep command on shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, logs, subshell

I have a log file and I am trying to write a shell script to find multiple strings in a file on multiple lines.

For example if I see the phrases `"class=com.comcast.parker.GetCurrentAudioLanguageResponse"` and `"status:OK"` together in the logs, I should print `getAudioLanguage SUCCESSFUL` else `getAudioLanguage FAILED`.
So my shell script goes like this:

```
logfile=$1

if grep "{\"class\":\"com.comcast.parker.GetCurrentAudioLanguageResponse\"" jags.txt | grep "{\"status\":\"OK\"" | wc -l ; then
    echo "getAudioLanguage SUCCESSFUL"
fi
if grep "{\"class\":\"com.comcast.parker.GetCurrentAudioLanguageResponse\"" $logfile | grep -q "GENERAL_ERROR" | wc -l ; then
    echo "getAudioLanguage FAILED"
fi
```

In the logs, I get status as `GENERAL_ERROR`, so it should print `FAILED`, but the output shows as `getAudioLanguage SUCCESSFUL` ..

Logfile:

```
160125-11:11:28.442500 [mod=SYS, lvl=INFO] [tid=2332] ======= Message is onRPCCall ======>
160125-11:11:28.442614 [mod=SYS, lvl=INFO] [tid=2332] Entering onRPCCallEvent for request ---> getAudioLanguage
160125-11:11:28.442845 [mod=SYS, lvl=INFO] [tid=2332] Received json request = {"event":1,"handler":1,"name":"onRPCCall","params":{"callGUID":"d75a5bab-6b29-4ab4-9f7e-3cf32d4a05b1","callParams":[{"getAudioLanguage":{}}],"class":"com.comcast.xre.events.XRERPCCallInfo","destinationSessionGUID":"ab00ebea-5f63-4619-9877-273a2bceea1d","method":"getAudioLanguage","sourceSessionGUID":"ab00ebea-5f63-4619-9877-273a2bceea1d"},"phase":"STANDARD","source":1}

160125-11:11:28.442920 [mod=SYS, lvl=INFO] [tid=2332] GetCurrentAudioLanguage : Entered
160125-11:11:28.442968 [mod=SYS, lvl=INFO] [tid=2332] pMainPlayer is NULL.
160125-11:11:28.443012 [mod=SYS, lvl=INFO] [tid=2332] getAudioLanguage: Get Audio Language returned ��v`>       T�=     T0~�t
160125-11:11:28.443676 [mod=SYS, lvl=INFO] [tid=2332] ====== Response sending is {"appId":1,"command":"CALL","commandIndex":5,"method":"generateAppEvent","params":[{"class":"com.comcast.xre.events.XREOutgoingEvent","name":"onRPCReturn","params":{"callGUID":"d75a5bab-6b29-4ab4-9f7e-3cf32d4a05b1","class":"com.comcast.xre.events.XRERPCReturnInfo","destinationSessionGUID":"ab00ebea-5f63-4619-9877-273a2bceea1d","method":"getAudioLanguage","returnVal":{"class":"com.comcast.parker.GetCurrentAudioLanguageResponse","status":"GENERAL_ERROR","statusMessage":"Getting Current Audio Language was unsuccessful."},"sourceSessionGUID":"ab00ebea-5f63-4619-9877-273a2bceea1d"}},"ab00ebea-5f63-4619-9877-273a2bceea1d"],"targetId":1,"targetPath":"","timestamp":0}
```

Comment: I see you're trying to approach JSON by simple grepping. Well this may work, however instead I would recommend you to get familiar with `jq` tool. It can actually "understand" JSON. Small example : `grep -Eo '(json request|Response sending is).*' a | cut -f 4- -d ' '  | jq '.params[].params.returnVal.status == "GENERAL_ERROR"' 2> /dev/null
true`As you can see it returns 'true' value which can later be easily used in some bash if loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWK may be a bit easier to use:

```
awk '/GetCurrentAudioLanguageResponse/ && /status\"\:\"GENERAL_ERROR/{ print "FAIL" } /GetCurrentAudioLanguageResponse/ && /status\":\"OK/ {print "SUCCESS"}  ' log.txt
```

In this code we match two patterns, and if patterns match - we run what's in the curly brackets. For `GetCurrentAudioLanguageResponse` and `status":"GENERAL_ERROR` we print "FAIL", and for patterns `GetCurrentAudioLanguageResponse` and `status\":\"OK` we print "SUCCESS"

Answer (score 0):

you should check the return status of the grep command. For eg., if my file contains --

```
  a.b.c.d status:FAILED
```

running the command

```
  [[ $(grep "a.b.c.d" log | grep "FAIL") ]] && echo  "FAILED"

 FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd offer you to use **sed** to parse log-file:

```
sed -n '
/{"class":"com.comcast.parker.GetCurrentAudioLanguageResponse"/{
    /"GENERAL_ERROR"/{
        c\getAudioLanguage FAILED
        p
        q
    }
    /"status":"OK"/{
        c\getAudioLanguage SUCCESSFUL
        h
    }
}
${
g
/SUCCESSFUL/p
}
' logfile
```